# Python pandas - DataFrame groupby and re-construct

Tags: python, pandas

I have a question for groupby() in pandas

If I have a DataFrame **"df"** like

```
    user  day  click
0   U1    Mon  15
1   U2    Mon  7 
2   U1    Wed  15 
3   U3    Tue  21
4   U2    Tue  15
5   U2    Tue  10
```

When I use **df.groupby(['user', 'day']).sum()**
It would be

```
            click  
user  day
U1    Mon   15
      Tue   NaN
      Wed   15
U2    Mon   7
      Tue   25
      Wed   NaN
U3    Mon   NaN
      Tue   21
      Wed   NaN
```

How can I get a DataFrame like this

```
day    Mon   Tue   Wed
user
U1     15    NaN   15
U2     7     25    NaN
U3     NaN   21    NaN
```

Which means transform one column to be the column name of DataFrame.
Is there any method to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use pivot function with day as columns and fill with clicks.

```
df.groupby(['user', 'day']).sum().reset_index()\
  .pivot(index='user',columns='day',values='click')
Out[388]: 
day    Mon   Tue   Wed
user                  
U1    15.0   NaN  15.0
U2     7.0  25.0   NaN
U3     NaN  21.0   NaN
```

Or you can only reset the second level index so you don't need to specify index column in the pivot function.

```
df.groupby(['user', 'day']).sum().reset_index(level=1)\
.pivot(columns='day',values='click')
```

Answer (score 2):

Just another way to use unstack():

```
df=df.groupby(['user', 'day']).sum().unstack('day') #unstack
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel() # drop first level column name
df
```

Output:

```
day  Mon  Tue  Wed
user            
U1   15.0 NaN  15.0
U2   7.0  25.0 NaN
U3   NaN  21.0 NaN
```

Comment: This seems to generate another level in the column index.

Comment: @Allen you are right, your solution is better way to go :) upvoted

Comment: In my application, I would use pivot(). This one is also a great solution. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Tiny.D Thanks. Your solution is more compact and I would use it if I don't mind the additional index level.